# What is Blast processing?

Tags: terminology, gaming-history, sega-genesis

Back in the Super Nintendo era, Sega's whole Marketing campaign hinged on one thing: Blast Processing.

I don't think I've ever seen it explained. It was just "WE GOT IT AND NINTENDONT."

So, What is blast processing and how was it such a revolutionary technology?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term "Blast Processing" was originally coined in reference to the high-speed DMA controller in Sega's Yamaha VDP graphics processor. This allowed much faster DMA transfer speeds than the SNES, along with faster RAM bandwidth.

[Source](https://www.giantbomb.com/blast-processing/3015-963/)

Comment: An 'Explain me like I'm 5' is necessary here I think

Comment: Bandwidth is how much information you can transfer. Like when you contract an ISP you choose your bandwidth.
Faster means that you can transfer that size of information in almost no time. It helps with better image resolution, and some other things listed on the source.
But this isn't the only way to achieve those things, just see how the mobile industry is doing with graphics today that intel and other well know companies from PC can't do.